# IOS How to make a carret pointer on top of a uilabel view pointing in a direction PHOTO]

Tags: ios, popup, uilabel, tagging

All I want to do is add a little pointer carret on my UILabels to use for image tagging. The user taps , the label appears with a carret above pointing at where the user tapped just like instagrams tagging.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think Instagram use custom `UIView`, where they override `drawRect:` method, to draw such figure. This custom View also contains `UILabel` on it.

Comment: Ok then the question becomes how do i draw a carret on a custom view.

Comment: I think it's one figure, so with UIBezierPath and moveToPoint/addLineToPoint